# How to fix CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Type'?

Tags: c#, log4net, .net-standard, log4net-configuration

I have this piece of code in .net framework class library project, I want to reuse it in.net standard class library project. It works as expected, but gives compilation error in .net standard project.

```
public FxLogger(string logger)
{
    ILog AppLogger = LogManager.GetLogger(logger);
```

Error:

```
CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Type'
```

log4net version in both application 2.0.8
I can see these methods declaration in the `LogManager` class

```
public static ILog GetLogger(string repository, string name);
public static ILog GetLogger(Assembly repositoryAssembly, Type type);
public static ILog GetLogger(string repository, Type type);
public static ILog GetLogger(Type type);
public static ILog GetLogger(Assembly repositoryAssembly, string name);
```

Comment: The only overload that takes a single parameter is expecting a Type parameter.

Comment: @MaxSzczurek yes I can see that, but I have a string, which I need to convert to `Type`, what to what type? and how?

Comment: What do you expect to happen from `LogManager.GetLogger("vivek nuna")`? Or any other string value?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov it is `LogManager.GetLogger(string.Empty)`

Comment: `What to what type and how?` Can you describe it?  As @AlexeiLevenkov said, What is expected behavior you want when you pass `LogManager.GetLogger(string.Empty)`

Comment: It will create an instance of `ILog` @PrasadTelkikar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 ILog AppLogger = LogManager.GetLogger(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly(),logger);
```

It looks like the .net framework method is defined as

```
public static ILog GetLogger(string name)
{
    return GetLogger(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly(), name);
}
```